# Allow a docker container to be in a docker network and also in the default docker network at the same time

Tags: docker

I have a docker container running inside a docker network named "ininetwork". Without specifying a network through the --network parameter this container gets within another network. The question is: How can I allow my container to be within those two networks at the same time?

Comment: The question is: "What are you trying to do?" Why the need for the "default" network?! This sounds like a xy problem: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378

Comment: I use the docker network ininetwork to establish connections to dbs within this docker network so I can use the names of those db containers instead of IP addresses. However, because of some real intranet safeguards my container must be in that default network to access other resources within this intranet.

Comment: This might sound strange but the my container can reach those intranet resources only if no  --network is specified.

Comment: Do your network container need to establish to other services in the intranet, or do they need to bey accessable in your intranet? For the first one, this should/couled be done via NAT from he host.

Comment: My container needs to access those other services existing in the intranet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you should *really* expand on the details in your question. Because this actually does sound more like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378). There is probably a much better way for you to solve this issue but without more details it's hard to say for us.

---

Using only the `docker` cli you can create a new container and afterwards connect it to an *additional* network:

```bash
# implicitly use default network
docker create --name my_app ....
# or explicitly specify connecting to the default network
docker create --name my_app --network=bridge

# addtionally connect container to ininetwork
docker network connect ininetwork my_app

# start container
docker start my_app
```

A much easier way though would be using some orchestration like `docker compose` (see the [`networks` attribute on services](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/05-services/#networks) and the [`networks` top-level element](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/06-networks/))